# How to check if stdin buffer is empty at TCL?

Tags: buffer, tcl, stdin

With [`fconfigure`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/fconfigure.htm) you can get and set channel options. `-buffering` specifies the type of buffering, and by default it is `line` for `stdin`.

Is there a way to check if the buffer at `stdin` is empty or not?

---

Please see this question: [How to check if stdin is pending in TCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755031/how-to-check-if-stdin-is-pending-in-tcl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you could set the channel mode to non-blocking and read from it. If the read returns 0 length then nothing was available. However, I suspect you mean to test for data present but not a complete line given your mentioning of the line buffering there. The fblocked command tests a channel for this. See [fblocked(1)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/fblocked.htm) for the details but for a line buffered channel this lets you know that an incomplete line is present.

Another useful command when reading stdin, if you are reading interactive script commands is to use the info complete command. With this you can just accumulate lines until info complete returns true then evaluate the whole buffer in one.

Comment: The [8.6 version of the same manpage](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/fblocked.htm) includes a worked example (for sockets, but they're not particularly special w.r.t. event handling).

Comment: Also, if you're using `info complete`, you need to put/keep a newline at the end of each line read as you accumulate them _including the one just read_.

Comment: It seems `fblocked stdin` works for `gets`, but it doesn't work for `read stdin Number`. At `stdin -blocking false` mode `read stdin BigNumber` acts like `gets`, so it returns empty string when there are some characters left with no newline symbol. However, in this case, after the call of `read stdin BigNumber` `fblocked stdin` returns false.

Comment: @Vahagn: I suspect in your case fblocked returns false because you've set the channel to non-blocking mode. Which is obvious if you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Tcl's input *buffer* with `chan pending input stdin` (requires at least Tcl 8.5). This does not indicate whether the OS has anything in its buffers though; those are checked by trying to read the data (`gets` or `read`) *or* by using a script that triggers off of a readable `fileevent`, when at least one byte is present. (Well, strictly what is actually promised is that an attempt to read a single byte won't block, but it could be because of an error condition which causes immediate failure. That's the semantics of how OS-level file descriptor readiness works.)

The `-buffering` option only affects output channels; it's useless on `stdin` (or any other read-only channel) and has no effect at all. Really. (It is, however, too much trouble to remove.)

Comment: At my working example `chan pending input stdin` returns 0 when `fblocked stdin` returns 1. Is this a bug?

Comment: @Vahagn: No that's correct. A channel is blocked if there is no input. So `fblocked` says it's blocked and `chan pending` says there's no input. Both mean the same thing for a blocking channel.

Comment: For reference, I only ever use `fblocked` with non-blocking channels.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but it sparked some research on my end and I found a function called `fileevent` which calls an event handler when the stream, i.e. stdin, has something in it that can be read.  It may be helpful.

Source: http://wiki.tcl.tk/880