# How to check if stdin is pending in TCL?

Tags: buffer, tcl, stdin

Consider the following code:

```
chan configure stdin -blocking false
while { true } {
    chan gets stdin
    if { chan blocked stdin } { break }
}
```

Here at the last line of the loop `chan blocked stdin` returns true in either cases: when there is no more input available at `stdin`, and when there there is some input available at `stdin`, but it doesn't end with a newline character. I need to distinguish these two cases.

How can I do that?

`chan pending input stdin` also returns `0` in both cases.

---

Here is the context where the above code is used.

```
proc prompt { } { puts -nonewline stdout "MyShell > "; flush stdout }

proc evaluate { } \
{
    chan configure stdin -blocking false
    while { true } {
        # for "stdin -blocking false" "read stdin" acts like "gets stdin"
        set part [chan read stdin 100]
        append command $part
        if { $part eq "" } { break }
    }
    chan configure stdin -blocking true
    # Here I want test if there are pending characters at stdin,
    # and while so, I want to wait for newline character.
    # It should be like this:
    # while { *the required test goes here* } {
    #    append command [chan gets stdin]\n
    # }
    while { ! [info complete $command] } { 
        append command [chan gets stdin]\n
    }
    catch { uplevel #0 $command } got
    if { $got ne "" } {
        puts stderr $got
        flush stderr
    }
    prompt
}

chan event stdin readable evaluate 
prompt
while { true } { update; after 100 }
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Read character by character as the key is pressed? What platform do you need to this on?

Comment: I am trying to write a shell similar to `tslsh`. The above code processes the input entered at the shell. If the input ends with a newline character, then the shell has to try to evaluate it, and otherwise, i.e. if there are pending characters at the input, then the shell has to wait for a newline character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running an interactive command interpreter with the event loop is quite possible, and is described [in some detail](http://wiki.tcl.tk/28268) on the Tcler's Wiki. However, if you're really just running Tcl commands then you should consider using the [`commandloop`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1968) command from the [TclX package](http://wiki.tcl.tk/207), as that takes care of the details for you.