# Disable Tcl's input buffering?

Tags: buffer, tcl

Does Tcl do any internal input buffering that's out of the script writers control? Will the following code possibly waste entropy (read more than 1 byte), and if so, how can I prevent it?

```
set stream [open "/dev/srandom"]
chan configure $stream -translation binary
set randomByte [chan read $stream 1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, tcl defaults to buffering and will waste enthropy (as much as a single `read` call will decide to hand over).

I thought that you can prevent it with

```
chan configure $stream -buffering none
```

But no, `-buffering` has no effect on input queue (it's not a single buffer internally).

However,

```
chan configure $stream -buffersize 0
```

does the trick, as I've seen from an experiment with `stdin` under `strace`. It makes *any* input go in `read`s (syscall) of size 1 (an argument to TCL `read` doesn't matter), so it would be extremely slow for normal use.

Comment: That's what I've always thought too, until I realized that [chan configure -buffering](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/chan.htm#M9) only mentions **output** buffering. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8750872/1246115.

Comment: @potrzebie thanks. Fortunately there is `-buffersize` which is useful for the situation in question.