# How to clearerr of stdin in Tcl after ctrl+d?

Tags: tcl, stdin

I recently [asked a question about reopening stdin in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194821/how-to-restart-stdin-after-ctrld) after passing EOF and now want the same behavior when using Tcl.

I can't seem to find a Tcl commmand doing what C `clearerr` would do. How can I pass ctrl+d to stdin at one time and later "reopen" stdin from the Tcl script? (Compiling an external library using C is cheating!)

Currently using Windows and thus ctrl+z but I assume they work similarly enough not to make a difference in this case. Here is some sample code:

```
set var {}; # declare var to hold the line
gets stdin var; # read a line
if {[string length $var]>0} {puts $var}; # print if read
if {[eof stdin]} { # if end-of-file reached
  puts {read from stdin was canceled. reopening just for fun}; # some debug message
  puts -nonewline "eof reached for stdin. enter something more to echo: "; flush stdout
  # clearerr() ???
  gets stdin var
  if {[string length $var]>0} {puts $var}
}
```

---

EDIT: Reading about `fileevent` I believe I can come up with a solution where user does not enter EOF at all to transition between stdin and GUI control.

Comment: `set stdin [open /dev/tty r]` might work on Linux.  I don't know if it is possible to reopen stdin on windows.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I pass ctrl+d to stdin at one time and later "reopen" stdin from the Tcl script?

I am not sure whether this expectation makes sense from a Tcl POV. If [eof] is caught on a channel, the Tcl channel for stdin is not closed (unless done so explicitly using [close], or Tcl shuts down completely), so there is no need to reopen it. Watch:

```
proc isReadable { f } {
  # The channel is readable; try to read it.
  set status [catch { gets $f line } result]
  if { $status != 0 } {
    # Error on the channel
    puts "error reading $f: $result"
    set ::DONE 2
  } elseif { $result >= 0 } {
    # Successfully read the channel
    puts "got: $line"
  } elseif { [eof $f] } {
      # End of file on the channel
      puts "end of file; just continue working"
      # set ::DONE 1
  } elseif { [fblocked $f] } {
    # Read blocked.  Just return
  } else {
    # Something else
    puts "can't happen"
    set ::DONE 3
  }
}

fconfigure stdin -blocking false
fileevent stdin readable [list isReadable stdin]

# Launch the event loop and wait for the file events to finish
vwait ::DONE
```

This is just a standard snippet from Tcl documentation, also used in [How to check if stdin is readable in TCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747652/how-to-check-if-stdin-is-readable-in-tcl). Aside, some comments from the answers and comments to your question at [How to restart stdin after Ctrl+D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194821/how-to-restart-stdin-after-ctrld) apply to Tcl as well. See Brad's comment using `open` or `seek stdin 0 end`, provided that the source of stdin is seekable.

Comment: edited the code sample. my problem is that once stdin has gone eof, I can't find a way to reset it to not being eof. that is what `clearerr` would have done, which is nowhere to be found in tcl docs. the second `gets stdin var` in my sample does not block since it is still eof.

Comment: for me (macOS), the second `gets stdin var` blocks just fine. I cannot verify on Win, I am afraid. Whatever the behaviour, blocking or non-blocking should not be affected by the (internal) EOF flag. You would have to provide more details on your setup. In any case, using the event loop (`fileevent`) is probably a better design choice, but I cannot tell from the few details shimmering through (GUI vs. CLI etc.)

Comment: besides: when you place the `[eof]` test in an appropriate (re-entering) branch in my snippet, you will see that the eof flag (the one Tcl maintains) will have been reset.

Comment: as for "the second gets stdin var in my sample does not block since it is still eof". turns out that windows default console works differently than their siblings under *nix and macOS (unless in raw mode). [gets] assumes line buffering, but on windows default console, ctrl-z (eof) does not produce a newline character along with it. therefore, the second [gets] does not show any effect. (kudos to sebres @ Tclers chat for explaining to me).

Comment: I also learnt that you can experience the same, no-newline behavior on *nix/ macOS using ctrl-d-d ... this will show the (unwanted) behaviour you are experiencing on windows also on those environments.

Comment: thanks! that would suggest clearerr is called internally on read, maybe... gonna check the tclers chat out and ask the experts myself :)

Comment: `clearerr` and `eof` have no play in this, if I understand this correctly; tclers chat is a good place to hang out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have a found a pure-TCL way around this problem: change the EOF character to something other than `Ctrl-Z`, read a dummy line (to remove the `Ctrl-Z` from the input buffer) and then reset the EOF character back to `Ctrl-Z`. Wrapped up in a procedure:

```
proc clearEOF {} {
    fconfigure stdin -eofchar { "\x01" "" }
    gets stdin dummy
    fconfigure stdin -eofchar { "\x1a" "" }
}
```

The choice of `\x01` is somewhat arbitrary: essentially anything that is not likely to be in the input buffer alongside the `Ctrl-Z` should do.

**Note**: This has only been tested on Windows 10 with TCL 8.6.9.

---

### Original Test Program

```
puts "Enter lines then Ctrl-Z <RETURN> to end"
while { [ gets stdin line ] >= 0 } {
    puts "Read: $line"
}
puts "Reached EOF"
puts "eof=[eof stdin]"
puts "Enter another line"
puts "gets=[gets stdin line]"
puts "Read: $line"
```

The *wish* is that after having read a number of lines, terminated by the EOF-marker (`Ctrl-Z`), you can then read another line. In practice, the EOF-state is not cleared, and the second call to `gets` does not wait for input and immediately returns `-1` (=EOF):

```
Enter lines then Ctrl-Z <RETURN>
Line1
Read: Line1
Line2
Read: Line2
^Z
Reached EOF
eof=1
Enter another line                <-- This does not wait
gets=-1
Read:
```

**Note**: despite the [TCL documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl24.html) including (my emphasis):

> `read ?-nonewline? fileID`
>
> Reads all the remaining bytes from fileID, and returns that string. If -nonewline is set, then the last character will be discarded if it is a newline. **Any existing end of file condition is cleared before the read command is executed**.

replacing the `gets` with something like `set line [ read stdin ]` makes no difference. Both commands return immediately. Having multiple repetitions of either command makes no difference: once TCL (and/or Windows<sup>**1**</sup>) thinks we've hit EOF, we *stay* at EOF!

---

### My Solution

After some playing around, trying every file-manipulation command I could find that TCL posses, I came up with the following:

```
puts "Enter lines then Ctrl-Z <RETURN>"
while { [ gets stdin line ] >= 0 } {
    puts "Read: $line"
}
puts "Reached EOF"
puts "eof=[eof stdin]"
puts "Reset EOF char"
fconfigure stdin -eofchar { "\x01" "" }
puts "eof=[eof stdin]"
puts "Reading dummy line"
puts "gets=[gets stdin line]"
fconfigure stdin -eofchar { "\x1a" "" }
puts "Enter another line"
puts "gets=[gets stdin line]"
puts "Read: $line"
```

The output of *this* version *does* wait for more input:

```
Enter lines then Ctrl-Z <RETURN>
Line 1
Read: Line 1
Line 2
Read: Line 2
^Z
Reached EOF
eof=1
Reset EOF char
eof=0                             <-- EOF has been cleared
Reading dummy line
gets=1                            <-- Read 1 character: the Ctrl-Z
Enter another line
More text                         <-- Waits for this to be typed
gets=9
Read: More text
```

My assumption of what's happening is that changing the EOF-character *does* reset the EOF status (whether this happens "*in TCL*" or "*in Windows*" I'm unsure). With a different EOF-marker in place, we can read the line containing the `Ctrl-Z` that has been left in the input buffer. (Depending on what you entered either side of the `Ctrl-Z`, this would normally also contain an end-of-line marker). With the `Ctrl-Z` disposed of, we can reset the EOF-character *back* to `Ctrl-Z` and carry on reading from `stdin` as normal.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> [This issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3421) on Microsoft's WSL GitHub page suggests that it could be Windows that is at fault: once the `Ctrl-Z` in the buffer, it always returns EOF, even when `clearerr()` is used.  My reading of "*Another bane for xplat programmers for the last 30 years, Ctrl-D on Unix and Ctrl-Z on Windows don't work the same.*" is that although the issue is against WSL, the *problem* is in Windows itself. Interestingly, the final comment (at time of writing) states "*Fixed in Windows Insider Build 18890*", but one might still need to call `clearerr()`.